# File System (fs) cannot find a file with space in it (Node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have developed a file system where I start with one folder and I display folders and files recursively as the user clicks on them.

I have no issue traversing where there is no white space between file names, but as soon as I enter a name with white space, I receive an error. Example:

```
Home
 .My Documents
 .Downloads
 .Desktop
```

the Error I receive by the fs is

```
REQUEST ./Home/My%20Documents
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './Home/My%20Documents'
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: './Home/My%20Documents' }
```

I tried to look it up, but can anyone give me a hint about how to get through this?

content.hbs

```
{{#each contents}}
            <tr>
                {{#if isFolder}}
                <td>
                    <a href="/{{name}}">
                    <div><img style="vertical-align:middle" src="folder.png" height="32" width="32" > <span style="margin-left: 20px">{{name}}</span></div></a> </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                {{else}}
                <td><div><img style="vertical-align:middle" src="file.png" height="32" width="32" > <span style="margin-left: 20px">{{name}}</span></div> </td>
                <td>{{size}} Mb</td>
                <td></td>
                {{/if}}
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you are receiving the path from a query string. Once it is clearly encoded you will have to do `path = decodeURIComponent(path)`.

Comment: Adding encodeURIComponent(req.url) actually gives something like 
`./Home/%2fMy%2520Downloads`
of the folders with space. and `./Home/%2FDesktop` for all the others. Now I receive file not found for every one.